# User input, verify if it is correct date format

Tags: php, date, textbox

I have a form where users enter info.  I want to be able to check if the date they input into my text field for date is in the correct format of mm/dd/yy.

How can I check what the user input against mm/dd/yy format, and if it is not correct, display an error telling them the date entered has to be in mm/dd/yy format.

Thanks

Comment: Verifying the format can be done client-side with `<input pattern="^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d$">` and/or in PHP. And to assert that it's also a valid date, use `strtotime()` and probe if it succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Far better to use a [date picker](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+picker) or three `<select>`s to ensure your user has no choice but enter the correct date format.

Comment: Or maybe just `<input type=date>` and let the browser or JS shim handle the tedios part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but using `explode()`, separate the incoming data into an array of [hopefully] three entries by using '/' as the split character.

Then check to see if the first value is in the range of 1..12, the second in the range of 1..31, and the last in the range of 0..99.

More complicated checking would ensure that for each month, the appropriate number of days is not exceeded (for extra credit, allow 29 in month 02 if and only if the year is evenly divisible by 4 (yes, this messes-up on all centuries wherein the first two digits are not divisible by 4, but you've limited to `yy` for the year format)).

If the input is too short (I'd say 5 characters to allow for 1/1/1), or too long (more than 8 characters), it is invalid.

The better format would be to **NOT** require the separator, and just make sure the string is 6 characters long, all numeric, and that each pair of digits is within your acceptable range.

Comment: `just make sure the string is 6 characters long` - surely you mean 8 characters? Remember the so-called millenium so-called bug...

Comment: @DaveRandom - the OP *specifically* indicated a date format of `mm/dd/yy` - that's only two digits for the year :)

Comment: fair enough, not your fault if the world ends and we all die because of someone elses poorly thought out app I suppose... :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
$date='12/12/2011';
$reg="#^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$#";

if (preg_match($reg, $date)) {
    echo "GOOD date.";
} else {
   echo "BAD date.";
}
```